# Sending Email in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, email

I set the from address as

```
System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("testemail@example.com", "TESTEMAIL")
```

Knowing that the first parameter is the address and the second is the display name, when I tried to send an email, I got

```
From: TESTEMAIL <testemail@example.com>
```

How can I do this without displaying

```
<testemail@example.com>?
```

I just want to see

```
From: TESTEMAIL
```

Comment: I'm going to suspect this is mail-client dependent as to what is "seen".

Comment: zzz.com currently points to a spammy domain registrar, who knows what it will point to tomorrow.  Use "example" for example domains. It's specifically reserved by ICANN for that purpose.

Comment: Why don't you want the recipient to see who the message is from?  Are you up to some nefarious, malevolent activity?

Comment: @Steve - it's a presentation issue, and something even legitimate operations would like to be able to do... not necessarily make the origin invisible, but at least hidden at first glance to show only the friendlier name.

Comment: @Joel - My question was directed at the original poster.

Comment: @Steve - Joel's right and because that's one of the requirements of my project. All of the applications in our company do send emails and I noticed that it is the standard but when I did my own, it is kinda different with the others that's why I have asked that question. Anyway, thanks all! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple bad assumptions here:

- Not everyone's e-mail client works as yours does. Some will already display only "TESTEMAIL", just like you want.  Others will ignore "TESTEMAIL" entirely and only display "testemail@example.com", and there's *nothing* you can do about it.  Many allow the user to choose how the user will see your name.  *None* allow you, the sender, to override the user's preference.

  I know you probably have messages come in to your own inbox this way, but that will happen only for addresses with e-mail domains that your e-mail client has chosen to trust, and there is nothing you can do to make other's e-mail clients trust your domain.
- That's only *if* your messages make it to their destination in the first place. If you send messages yourself, they stand a good chance of being filtered as spam somewhere along the way. You almost always need to use an established, reputable, service when sending e-mail from a web site.

Of course, those are moot if you're working on an intranet site sending mail entirely within your own organization... but in that case, "TESTEMAIL" vs "testemail@example.com" hardly matters.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send an email without specifying an email.

What you can do is specify a display name the way you are already doing, but how it will be displayed by the client is a call of the client, not yours.